# Mongoose Find - Exclude One Specific Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to fetch many documents via `Schema.find()`, but **exclude one specific document** via its id. Currently, my query looks like:

```
Product
    .find({
        $or: [
            { 'tags': { $regex: criteria, $options: 'i' }, },
            { 'name': { $regex: criteria, $options: 'i' }, },
        ],
    })
    .limit(10)
    .exec((err, similar) => {
        //...
    })
```

I tried to add `$not: { _id: someId }` to the query but that gives me an error, that `$not` ist not valid.

Comment: To use `$not` you should specify the operator:
`Product.find({ _id: {$not: {$eq: someId}}})`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `$ne` which stands for `not equal`

```
Product.find({ _id: {$ne: someId}})
```

So the whole query would look like

```
Product
    .find({
        $and: [
             { _id: {$ne: someId} },
             { $or: [
                   { 'tags': { $regex: criteria, $options: 'i' }, },
                   { 'name': { $regex: criteria, $options: 'i' }, },
             ]},
         ]
    })
    .limit(10)
    .exec((err, similar) => {
        //...
    })
```

Comment: is there a way to exclude multiple ids? {$ne: someId, someIdAgain} doesn't work :/

Comment: nevermind, I found it. I used your second example and added more ids that way. thank you.

Comment: I am using `"mongoose": "^5.3.12",` it does not runs.

Answer (score 1):

For Not equal to multiple Id in mongooses.

```
const products = await Product.find({
  _id: { $nin: [id1, id2, id3] },
});
```